# Dog is Animal but list<Dog> is not list<Animal>. How to use it safely in a generic/polymorphic function?

Tags: java, c++, polymorphism

It is well-known that a `Dog` is an `Animal` but `List<Dog>` is not `List<Animal>`
([SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p?lq=1))

Anyway, if we have a function

```
void f(Animal a1, Animal a2); // Java

void f(Animal * a1, Animal * a2) // C++
```

We can safely use f() passing in objects of type `Dog / Dog*`

Now suppose, we  want to generalize it as if it has many arguments of type Animal
by using a `List` of them (and not specifically a multiple argument list ... ).
The `List` is not going to be modified by the function, 
adding a `Cat` to a `List<Dog>` for instance.

This:

```
void fg (List<Animal>); // Java
void fg (List<Animal *>) // C++
```

is not going to allow a call passing in a `List<Dog> / List<Dog*>` value.

What is the way to go?

May be in Java

```
void fg (List<? extends Animal>)
```

and in C++

```
template<T>
void fg (List<T>)
```

Is that ok?
Are there other alternatives?

Thanks.

Comment: `f(Animal... animals)`

Comment: But, yes, `List<? extends Animal>` works for a consumer ([but the `List` is considered a producer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)).

Comment: @Sotirios beside of `f(Animal ... animals)`.

Comment: This is quite clearly 2 questions (how in Java and how in C++), not 1 question.  Please post single questions at a time.

Comment: @Yakk. It is the same question at the end.

Comment: @cibercitizen1 no, it is not.  There are things you can reasonably do in one language that cannot reasonably be done in the other.  The superficial resemblance of generics and other syntax elements notwithstanding.  On top of that, the set of experts in both Java and C++ is going to be small.

Answer (score 2):

> The list is not going to be modified by the function [...]. What is the way to go?

In Java, declare a parameter of type `List<? extends Animal>`. This provides a wildcard bounded by Animal type argument to the `List` generic parameter. You can read that as a *list of any **unknown** type that extends `Animal`*. The fact that it is an **unknown** type means that the only type that can be used wherever a value of the `List`'s type parameter `T` is expected is the null type, whose only value is `null`.

A `List<Dog>` is a type that fits that description, so is a `List<Cat>`.

Comment: You may use the interface `Iterable<? extends Animal>` to make it clear it is read only